# Getting 404 error in browser console when using iframes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using iframe in angularjs. I have declared a variable which holds the iframe url.Functionalities are working fine but browser console shows 404 error that the variable is not found.

Below is the JS code snippet:

```
scope.classifierSrc = null;
scope.classifierSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl( CONSTANTS.STATUS_URL+response.result.username+"&password="+response.result.passw‌​ord +"&sam_id="+response.result.sample_id+"&r_id="+response.result.run_id +"&p_id="+response.result.project_id+"&l_id="+response.result.library_id); });
```

And HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <iframe width="100%" height="450" ng-src="{{classifierSrc}}" class="varentiframe"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide JS code and HTML code. Without this nobody will help you.

Comment: welcom to stackoverflow! please read this before asking question:-http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: share iframe code to debug easily

Comment: will you share the code you run

Comment: try using ng-src and share the code how you are using classifierSrc variable in the HTML

Comment: Sorry i'm not familiar with stackoverflow.I can share the html code.                   `<div class="modal-body">
        <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="{{classifierSrc}}" class="varentiframe">
        </iframe>
      </div>`

Comment: Angular JS code to see classifierSrc

Comment: Actually i 'm having a directory in my root folder which is given from my client.And i'm only giving that folder path in this variable.Below is the only line of code written in JS.    `scope.classifierSrc             ='variantclassifier/';`  variantclassifier is the folder name

Comment: There is also another variable 'urlSrc' which is used in this way.I can share that JS code. `scope.urlSrc =$sce.trustAsResourceUrl( CONSTANTS.STATUS_URL+response.result.username+"&password="+response.result.password
                            +"&sam_id="+response.result.sample_id+"&r_id="+response.result.run_id
                            +"&p_id="+response.result.project_id+"&l_id="+response.result.library_id);
                        });`

Comment: This error can't be viewed in developer machine,Only seen randomly in client machine

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error means that some  resource at a specific URL your app need can't be found. Check the error description to find out what file it is. (You might have a typo, or the URL wrong)

Comment: http://myproject.local/public/%7B%7BclassifierSrc%7D%7D 404(Not found)...This is the error,classifierSrc is the variable which holds the src.And i'm intializing this variable as null.File is angular.js file.What can i do with angularjs library file?